# Set target of UIButton to IBAction not working (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Is there any reason the following code for setting the target of a UIButton to an IBAction programmatically shouldn't work?

.h

```
- (IBAction)googleIt:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
UIButton *google = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 15.0, 280.0, 40.0)];
[google addTarget:self action:@selector(googleIt:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(that's in view did load, this is after that)

```
-(IBAction)googleIt:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```

Edit: added a : after googleIt, still doesn't work. When I add a button in storyboard and just connect it to the IBAction, that works, so the IBAction itself is not the problem.

Edit: full button code requested

```
 UIButton *google = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 15.0, 280.0, 40.0)];
[google addTarget:self action:@selector(googleIt:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[google setTitle:@"Google 'em" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[google setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
google.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[charityInfo addSubview:google];
```

EDIT: DONE! User action not enabled. Can somebody put that answer and I'll markas true?

Comment: Are you also adding the button to the view hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, the button is added in the view properly and display with several properties I have left out for brevities sake.

Comment: can you post the rest of the button creation code? what you have posted so far looks ok

Comment: I don't want to sound stupid, but are you sure that the button displayed in the UI is the same that you are creating in the code ? Because from what I see, the code should work.

Comment: I know right! It should blinking work. Ugh.

Comment: does charityInfo have user interaction enabled? everything with the button code looks fine

Comment: I'll try that, that actually struck me just before you posted that! Thanks so much Andrew hold on lemme see, but I'm sure that's it.

Comment: Somebody put "make sure the parent view has user interaction enabled" as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: updated my answer to reflect both changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the selector for googleIt is missing the colon to indicate that it takes an argument

it should be

```
[google addTarget:self action:@selector(googleIt:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Edit, added from comments: the selector was part of the problem, but user interaction was not enabled on the view the button was contained in.

Comment: Thanks man, I wondered why xCode wanted me to add that. I've added it now, but the button still does nothing when clicked, but at least I know that I need a colon. Any other thoughts?

Comment: have you added a log or breakpoint to the googleIt method to verify its called?

Comment: Yep, it's not being called when I click that button. the UIButton just isn't being added as an outlet for the action for some reason, but everywhere I look that is the exact syntax for adding it.

Comment: normally with UIButtons you don't alloc init them..instead you call the buttonWithType UIButton class method then set the frame. something like UIButton *google = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]

Comment: Is there some change that's the problem?

Comment: If so, I need to still do UIButton *google = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 15.0, 280.0, 40.0)]; so how would I do that with UIButtonTypeCustom?

Comment: Ok I set it as a UiButtonTypeCustom and then set the frame, that's not the issue.